# KDE: how to restart IBus without logging out?

Tags: kde, ibus

Sometimes `ibus` crashes and the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> switch language hotkey stops working, and the taskbar ibus language icon (picture here) disappears, yet in the background I'll still notice some `ibus-daemon` processes are running...

What is the best way to restart `ibus` without ending your whole desktop session?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So far the best solution I've found is:

```
pkill ibus-x11
# make sure no ibus-* processes are still running, kill them if they are
/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim
```

This seems to be a feasible workaround, but curious if there's a better way to recovered a crashed `ibus` without logging out and ending your session.

If that still doesn't work, perhaps restarting the plasma session without logging out is your next best step:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out